# How to work out Linux file system delta?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I want to work out exactly which files changed as a result of installing and configuring some software.

What is the most effective way to do that?

Comment: You can compare the `mtime` of each file with your installation time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about "*most* effective" as that's rather opinion-based.  But one fairly comprehensive way is by using `find`:

```
sudo find / -ctime 0 > files_changed_in_last_24_hours.txt
```

You'll need to clean up the output by, removing all the entries that start with `/proc` or `/sys/`:

```
sed -i '/^\/proc/d;/^\/sys/d' files_changed_in_last_24_hours.txt
```

Or you can do this in one command like so:

```
sudo find / -ctime 0 | sed '/^\/proc/d;/^\/sys/d' > my_list_of_files.txt
```

This is equivalent to the previous two commands.

This will include more than just the files you want, but it will be a very nice complete list of (as the title indicates) the files changed in the last 24 hours.  (Specifically, it will be files with `ctime` in the last 24 hours.)

You should look at `man find` to get narrower time windows than 24 hours, of course.